# Trouble adding ';' in Perl regex

Tags: perl

I'm trying to check for ";" also in the if loop, but If I include ";" or "\;" it doesn't work.. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here..

```
# Check "!", "[]" and "#"
 while ( <$fh> ) {
  if ( m/^(?:[!\[]|#\s)/ ) {
      output $current, $fhout;
      $current = [ $_ ];
  }
  else {
      push @$current, $_;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your IF check with ";". Where did you add it, before "]" or after it?

Comment: You don't have to escape `;`. It's not a special regex character.

Answer (score 3):

No need for the non-capturing parentheses, `/^[!#;]|^\[]/` should be fine:

```
perl -Mstrict -wE "do{ say $_, ' matches' if /^[!#;]|^\[]/} for qw/ ;23 25df fg43 !sdf [56y ]][s #faw []13 /;"
```

---

#### Output

> ```
> Possible attempt to put comments in qw() list at -e line 1.
> ;23 matches
> !sdf matches
> #faw matches
> []13 matches
> ```